# check/change manifest groups (init -g option) on "repo"?

Tags: repo

On google-repo, in init, I can set a branch (-b), a manifest (-m) and a set of optional parts (Manifest groups, -g).

I cannot seem to find much information about the latter:

On an existing clone, how can I check which manifest groups were chosen, and how can I change them?

Doing a wholly new create/init/sync for a new copy is not really a solution.